# Tunnelling server traffic throuh SSH when port forwarding on network is unavailable?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

## Setup

At *home*, I have a little Raspberry Pi 3 that runs services that are exposed to the internet. For example, it is running a HTTP server. I will call this server `raspberry`. I can manage `raspberry` remotely via SSH: I have opened port `22` on my router at *home* and therefore traffic to my public IP for this port is forwarded to `raspberry`. So far so good.

`raspberry`'s architecture is `arm64` and it runs `FreeBSD` which makes it impossible (apparently, I tried hacking around, but no dice) for me to run a game server (UrbanTerror 4.3) on it.

I also have another machine, which is a ThinkPad (later on: `thinkpad`)  running `OpenBSD` and it has an `amd64` architecture, which *does* in fact allow me to run the desired server. From `thinkpad`, I can access `raspberry` by using SSH.

## Question

I am currently not at *home*, but on a different network, actually *abroad*. I have an irresistible urge to host my server now, but I couldn't manage to do it on `raspberry`, as I said.

**Would it be somehow possible to run the server on `thinkpad` and tunnel all traffic through `raspberry` (since I can expose that to the internet, whereas here, *abroad*, I do not have administrator rights to the router)?**

Essentially, what I want is to run the server on `thinkpad` as if I were running it on `raspberry` in terms of networking. That is the server would appear in server browsers and players would be able to connect: the traffic would arrive at `raspberry` through port eg `27900` and it would be sent over the internet via SSH to `thinkpad`.

PS I realize this would probably result in poor performance due to relaying the traffic through SSH but I would still like to try.

Thank you in advance and sorry for the long post!

## EDIT 2018-12-14: Here is what I have already tried

So I need a *reverse SSH tunnel* for this. I created a tunnel from `thinkpad` like so

```
ssh -N -R :27960:localhost:27960 <raspberry's public IP>
```

The tunnel is created successfully. I checked with `netstat` on `raspberry` and it is indeed listening on `*:27960` (but TCP; is this a problem? UrbanTerror, like other games, uses UDP). Now I launched the server on `thinkpad` and again, with `netstat`, I saw that it's listening on `*:27960` (UDP).

I tried opening an UrbanTerror client on `thinkpad` and connecting to `<raspberry's IP>`, but it didn't work. To debug, I tried the same while running

```
tcpdump -n -e -ttt -i ue0 | grep 27960
```

on `raspberry`. When I attempted joining my server through `raspberry` from UrbanTerror, the following appeared in the dump:

```
188.112.111.89.27961 > 192.168.0.33.27960: UDP, length 16
192.168.0.33 > 188.112.111.89: ICMP 192.168.0.33 udp port 27960 unreachable
```

(I stripped the output for brevity)

`188.112.111.89` is the current public IP of `thinkpad` and `192.168.0.33` is of course `raspberry`. Why is port `27960` unreachable? Clearly, according to `netstat`, `thinkpad` is listening on that port.

Just to test connectivity, I tried running `nc -l 27960` on `thinkpad` and `nc localhost 27960` on `raspberry`: I could communicate in both directions w/o problems.

I think it's also worth mentioning that I have `OpenBSD`'s `pf` packet filter running on both machines but I have disabled it for troubleshooting.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Does "remote port forwarding" ring a bell? Have you read `man ssh`? In [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1382025/432690) the setup is similar (translation: "Plex" -> "thinkpad"; "remote server" -> "raspberry").

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Keywords are "ssh" and "tunnel" (unsurprisingly). Both the man page and the web have lots of details. If you can't set it up, edit your question with what you've tried, and what doesn't work.

Comment: @dirkt I have updated my question as you asked.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can do this. Easiest is to temporarily create ssh tunnel to router web interface via `raspberry`. Open UDP on router to `thinkpad` (UrbanTerror server only uses UDP and default port is 27960). After that, players would be able to connect to your public IP.

If you don't want to open another port on router. Each players will have to have access to SSH to your `raspberry` and make SSH port forwarding tunnel via TCP port 22 and perform UDP to TCP relay on their machine. You can do this with socat:

```
Raspberry side: socat tcp4-listen:27900,reuseaddr,fork UDP:`thinkpad`:27960

Players side: socat -T15 udp4-recvfrom:27960,reuseaddr,fork tcp:localhost:27900
```

Comment: Sorry, either I wasn't clear enough or you have missed something. I cannot open the port to `thinkpad` as that box is not even on my home network.

I am not sure about the second solution you provided, I would like everybody to be able to connect, without having the need to SSH.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you and your `thinkpad` are *abroad*, the `raspberry` is *at home*, and you can remotely configure your router *at home* to open new ports on the `raspberry`.

TCP vs UDP makes a big difference, because `ssh` can only tunnel TCP. So you additionally need to convert between those.

The latency in the complete setup will be very noticeable.

You need to

1) Configure your router *at home* to forward UDP port 27960 to the `raspberry`.

2) On the `raspberry`, convert with `socat` between UDP and TCP, the latter say on port 27900.

3) Create a ssh tunnel from the `thinkpad` to the `raspberry`; the direction will depend on the `socat` commands. Say, port 27900 on both sides.

4) On the `thinkpad`, use `socat` again to convert between TCP 27900 and UDP 27960.

IIRC you have to be a bit careful which of the UDP variants to use with `socat` so it works in both directions. I'd need to test this, but I don't have the time right now, so I can't give you concrete commands right now. You also have to set it up on the correct order, so that the "listening" services are started first, before they get a connection from the other steps.